# JQuery Loop Through Variables to change element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Completely new to JQuery so read some of the documentation here:

https://api.jquery.com/click/

I am trying to change an input from disabled to enabled on user click. I used this code which works fine:

```
$('#edit1').click(function(){
        $('#doc1').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

I then wanted to loop through it for every value of edit1 and doc1 i.e. edit2 and doc2...etc.

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var max = 6;
        var i = 0;
        var x = 0

        if (x < max) {
            i++
            x++;

            $('#edit${i}').click(function () {
                $('#doc${x}').removeAttr('disabled');
            })
        }
    };
```

And can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rockhopper92/9oapaf1k/

Now this does somehow "look" wrong to me but can't put my finger on it. I have a feeling it's to do with where I'm opening and closing my brackets or some really fundamental error like the opening line '$(document).ready(function()'

This is my first attempt at JQuery so any general pointers would be a massive help to me.

Comment: You can use it a bit more simple, check this http://jsfiddle.net/9oapaf1k/4/

Comment: Thank you @CarstenLøvboAndersen this works perfectly. Do you mid me asking what exactly it is doing though just so I understand for future?

Comment: Rockhopper here is a new version with explanation http://jsfiddle.net/rog2td14/

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9oapaf1k/5/)

- Using `if` instead of `while`
- Not taking correct `index` and using `x` which would have become `max` by the time `click` is executed.
- Not using the closing brace `)` for `document.ready`.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max = 6;
  var i = 0;

  while (i < max) {
    i++;

    $('#edit' + i).click(function() {
      var index = this.id.substring( 4 );
      $('#doc' + index).removeAttr('disabled');
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js">


</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="edit1">
      <input type="text" id="doc1" value="Document 1" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="edit2">
      <input type="text" id="doc2" value="Document 2" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit3">
      <input type="text" id="doc3" value="Document 3" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit4">
      <input type="text" id="doc4" value="Document 4" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit5">
      <input type="text" id="doc5" value="Document 5" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit6">
      <input type="text" id="doc6" value="Document 6" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**

- I am using **simple concatenation** of `i` instead of template literals.

Comment: Thank you so much this is working perfectly. I also really appreciate the explanation. Seems obvious now you've pointed it out! Thank you for taking the time :)

Answer (score 0):

What you might find easier is to use classes instead of ids. Attach an `edit` class to each div then target those with the jQuery selector. That way you won't have to use a loop.

You target the class with `$('.edit')`, and then in the callback you target the `input` within the current selector context (`this`). You can then switch off the disable property.

(In the HTML I've replaced the value with a placeholder instead.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
    $('input', this).prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="edit">
      <input type="text" id="doc1" placeholder="Document 1" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
      <input type="text" id="doc2" placeholder="Document 2" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
      <input type="text" id="doc3" placeholder="Document 3" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use template literals use backticks ``` `` ``` isntead of `''`, if not you can use plain javascript :

```
$('#edit'+ i).click(function(){
        $('#doc'+x).removeAttr('disabled');
  })
```

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max = 6;
var i = 0;
var x = 0

if(x < max){
i++
x++;

$('#edit'+ i).click(function(){
        $('#doc'+x).removeAttr('disabled');
  })
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max = 6;
    var i = 0;
    var x = 0; //no need

    for (i=0;i<=max;i++) {    

        $('#edit'+i).click(function () {
            $('#doc'+i).removeAttr('disabled');
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Find all divs with id which starts with edit and listen for a click event
   $('[id^="edit"]').click(function() {
     // find the input for the clicked div
     var doc = $(this).find($('input'));
     // remove the attribute
     doc.removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 8px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js">


</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="edit1">
      <input type="text" id="doc1" value="Document 1" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="edit2">
      <input type="text" id="doc2" value="Document 2" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit3">
      <input type="text" id="doc3" value="Document 3" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit4">
      <input type="text" id="doc4" value="Document 4" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit5">
      <input type="text" id="doc5" value="Document 5" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id="edit6">
      <input type="text" id="doc6" value="Document 6" disabled><i class="far fa-edit"></i>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are several way to do this without the use of a loop.

You can add a class to your element and listen for a click event.

```
$('.yourClass').click(function(){
 $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

You can also listen to every click on an element with id starting with something.

If you know the element type then: (eg: replace 'element' with 'div')

```
$("element[id^="edit"]").click(function(){
 $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

If you don't know the element type:

```
$("[id^="edit"]").click(function(){
 $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

This will enable/disable respective input when you click edit icon.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $(document).on("click", ".fa-edit" , function(e)
   {
      var element = $(this);
      if(element.parent().children('input').attr('disabled') == 'disabled')
      element.parent().children('input').attr('disabled' , false);
      else
      element.parent().children('input').attr('disabled' , true);


   });

});
```